# Swift Enum case is not a member of type

Tags: swift, enums

*I know there are many questions named similarly, but as far as I can tell this is a new one*

Here is a basic example of what I want to do, I'm not sure why it doesn't work :

```swift
enum Test  {
    case A(Int)
    case B(String)
}
let a : Test.A //Enum case 'A' is not a member of type 'Test'
```

But it is ! What's happening here ?

Comment: Note that it is Swift naming convention to start your cases with a lowercase letter. Btw It should be `let a: Test`. `A` is not type it is a case

Comment: AFAIK You can not force an object to be a specific case of an enumeration.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?  The use case isn't obvious from the question.  If it's to use it as a flag you want `a` to be a constant of Test.a(int), not a type of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type is actually `Test`. `A` and `B` are the cases.
Actually, you should use lower case for the cases, so it should be:

```
enum Test  {
    case a(Int)
    case b(String)
}
```

You could use this enum as follows:

```
var myVar: Test

myVar = Test.a(0) // long version
myVar = .a(10) // short version: "Test" is inferred
myVar = .a(125)

myVar = .b("Hello")
myVar = .b("World")
```

Answer (score 1):

The type is Test, not A.

```
let a: Test = Test.A(2)
```

Comment: Swift is a type inferred language. `Test` again  is redundant `let a: Test = .A(2)`

Comment: Well that is kind of a problem I guess, I'll have to rethink a few things. Enforcing specific enum cases would have been very useful

Comment: @Crysambrosia Just create nested types

Comment: The answer was writen this way to make it clear to the op. Yes, one Test is redundant. And again yes, capital cases are not in line with the general styleguide.